# Calculate mean for several columns in Spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm looking for a way to calculate some statistic e.g. mean over several selected columns in Spark using Scala. Given that `data` object is my Spark `DataFrame`, it's easy to calculate a mean for one column only e.g.

```
data.agg(avg("var1") as "mean var1").show
```

Also, we can easily calculate a mean cross-tabulated by values of some other columns e.g.:

```
data.groupBy("category").agg(avg("var1") as "mean_var1").show
```

But how can we calculate a mean for a List of columns in a DataFrame? I tried running something like this, but it didn't work:

```
scala> data.select("var1", "var2").mean().show
<console>:44: error: value mean is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
       data.select("var1", "var2").mean().show
                                   ^
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what you need to do

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

import spark.implicits._
val df1 = Seq((1,2,3), (3,4,5), (1,2,4)).toDF("A", "B", "C")

data.select(data.columns.map(mean(_)): _*).show()
```

Output:

```
+------------------+------------------+------+
|            avg(A)|            avg(B)|avg(C)|
+------------------+------------------+------+
|1.6666666666666667|2.6666666666666665|   4.0|
+------------------+------------------+------+
```

This works for selected columns

```
data.select(Seq("A", "B").map(mean(_)): _*).show()
```

Output:

```
+------------------+------------------+
|            avg(A)|            avg(B)|
+------------------+------------------+
|1.6666666666666667|2.6666666666666665|
+------------------+------------------+
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I know this approach, but it's not correct. It applies mean on all columns of a dataframe.

Comment: That's right! Now it's working nicely. I will accept your answer. Thanks.

Comment: Glad that helped you :) and thanks for accepting as an answer

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the dataset you can do this:

```
ds.describe(s"age")
```

Which will return this:

```
    summary age  
    count   10.0 
    mean    53.3   
    stddev  11.6
    min     18.0
    max     92.0
```